# Type 'typeof import("*.svg")' is not assignable to type 'string'. ts(2322)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, svg

The below line is throwing the above error in `tsx` file

```
import MySvgImg from "images/mySvgImage.svg";

<img src={MySvgImg} alt="This line throws error" />
```

I handled the SVG imports in the `global.d.ts`

```
declare module "*.svg" {
  const ReactComponent: any;
  export const ReactComponent;
}
```

I also included global.d.ts in my `tsconfig.json`

```
 "include": ["src/**/*", "global.d.ts"],
```

Comment: Can we assume that your project was scaffolded with `create-react-app`?

Comment: You've declared the "*.svg" module as exporting a `ReactComponent`, which is not a string. `<MySvgImg/>` would be more appropriate syntax for the placement of a component.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can import SVG as a component.

```
import { ReactComponent as MySvgImg } from "images/mySvgImage.svg";
```

With this import, you can use the SVG icon as a normal React component

```
      <MySvgImg />
```

You might need to change the `global.d.ts` if you get a new error saying there is no named import.

```
declare module "*.svg" {
  const ReactComponent: any;
  export { ReactComponent };
}
```